# Connectivity relation

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Tiling of a plane fills the plane with a set of polygons.

Connectivity of a vertex is # edges coming into it which equals #
of faces it touches.

Suppose the average # of edges on a polygon is x. 
This equals the average # of vertices on a polygon. 
Consider a tiling with constant connectivity k.

Find a relation between x and k.

Am I supposed to relate this to eulers characteristic, to find a relationship

Answer (score 1):

Euler characteristic would be the way to go. If you have $F$ polygons, then you have $E=\frac x2F$ edges and $V=\frac xkF$ vertices. Euler characteristic tells you something along the lines of

$$\chi=V-E+F=\left(\frac xk-\frac x2+1\right)F$$

The formula as it stands might not be completely correct for a finite subset of the inifnite tiling, since at the boundary the connectivity and polygon size figures may be different from the average case. But as you are interested in the limit $F\to\infty$, the boundary becomes less important than the interior, and the only thing that matters is the fact that the above $\chi$ remains finite. Which it only can if it remains zero. So you get the equation

\begin{align*}
\frac xk-\frac x2+1 &= 0 \\
2x-kx+2k&=0
\end{align*}

I must confess that at first I still had some nagging doubts about how I treated the argument about the boundary becoming irrelevant, and of $\chi=0$. But I did recall that [*The Symmetries of Things*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812205) did something similar. I later had a look at that book, and the argument is *very* similar, except for the fact that due to the regularity of symmetric tilings, they can give some more precise bounds on the impact of the boundary.